# Trying to understand QML Buttons and anchors

Tags: qt, qml

I have the following simple QML:

```
  Button
  {
    id: aButton

    text: "a button"

    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.bottom: aRectangle.bottom

    onClicked: {
      console.log( aButton.height )
      console.log( aButton.implicitHeight )
    }
  }

  Rectangle {
    id: aRectangle

    width: 200
    height: 25

    color: "red"
    border.color: "red"
    border.width: 1

    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.top: parent.top
  }
```

The QML produces the following output.

[image: output]

what surprised me is that button is visually offset from the bottom of the rectangle by 6 pixels. What I was expecting is for them to be aligned.

What is the correct way to make this happen?

Comment: Your code works for me. The code you provided doesn't exactly match the image you are showing. (e.g. The text in the code is lower-case vs upper-case in the image.) Are you sure there's nothing else you're leaving out? A minimal reproducible example would help.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using the Material Theme which inserts an inset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of Material theme (you should have mentioned ;-) ). They have put a offset inside the thing that is technically the button, but outside of what is visually the button. This is done to have some room for the shadow. It is indeed 6 pixels.

If you wish to overcome this, you can use the 'bottomInset' property:

```
Button
{
    id: aButton

    text: "a button"

    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.bottom: aRectangle.bottom
    anchors.bottomInset: 0
}
```

Comment: With some further investigation, I found https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#control-layout which describes the layout properties of a control. Here I saw inset mentioned. Rather than setting ```anchors.bottomMargin: -6```, I think the better solution is ```anchors.bottomInset: 0```. It results in no visual changes to the button itself. If you agree and wanted to modify your answer, I will mark yours as the answer. Of course, setting all of the insets to zero will provide for the visually predictable layout I was seeking.

Comment: @JamesHudson you are right, I had forgotten about insets, this is indeed the better solution, so I updated the answer